# Iterate through JSON

Tags: jquery, json

i'm wondering how i could loop through this json data to get the values inside it with jquery? All i've got is `undefined`. I'm using `$.ajax.get()` to get the file then i'm trying to loop through it to get data inside it. The JSON looks like this...

The result from the get is a string!

```
    [
    {
        "category": "anti-social-behaviour", 
        "persistent_id": "", 
        "location_subtype": "STATION", 
        "month": "2012-11", 
        "location": {
            "latitude": "52.6313999", 
            "street": {
                "id": 1447707, 
                "name": "Leicester"
            }, 
            "longitude": "-1.1252999"
        }, 
        "context": "", 
        "id": 18782816, 
        "location_type": "BTP", 
        "outcome_status": {
            "category": "Under investigation", 
            "date": "2012-11"
        }
    }
]
```

Regards /Haris!

Comment: is the result of the `get()` an object or a string?

Comment: Its a string, sorry for not mentioning!

Comment: Any chance to see some JavaScript code? jQuery AJAX methods decode JSON automatically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you're getting through ajax call and youre json returned is on some var data, you can parse using $.each

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
  //use obj.id and obj.name here, for example:
  alert(obj.name);
});
```

Comment: you answered that before me :)

Comment: :) just recently faced this prob :D

Comment: It seems $ajax is parsing it to string directly, how can i make it an object cuz i was trying your example before asking here and i guess its beacuse it not and object i get undefined...!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop through the items like this:

```
$.each(obj, function(i, val) {
    alert(val.category);
    alert(val.location.latitude);
    alert(val.location.street.id);
});​
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yc5VH/)

Comment: Thanks! I helped me alot with .location.street.id :D!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that you have a json object and not a string.
After:

```
for(var i in JSONObject){ // code goes here }
```

Remember that you can also call the elements in the object using it direct key value.

Exp. ObjName.keyname

Comment: JSON and object are contradictory terms. JSON is always a string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was it of course wasn't an object and thats why i couldnt interate through the json... So i used:
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON();

and everything works perfectly!